# Two package.json files in nativescript project

Tags: npm, nativescript

Somehow I have two package.json files in my nativescript project. Am I supposed to have both of them? If not, any idea why they would be both be there? As per [this page](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/using-npm-modules-and-nativescript-plugins) I'm guessing I can delete the package.json file in the app folder? I'm pretty sure I've only ever ran npm install from the root of my project. Sometimes I also run tns install at the root of my project.

```
my-project
    ├── app
    │   └── package.json <-- can I delete this?
    ├── package.json
    ├── node_modules
    └── platforms
        ├── android
        └── ios
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you delete `app/package.json`, you won't be able to run the application because it won't find the main JavaScript file (the one used to bootstrap your app).

I agree that it is kind of weird that you need both of them. I thought the same thing at first, but I couldn't find a way to make it work without it.

Comment: One package.json in root is for packages and inside app is from template which points to bootstrap file and was downloaded while project was created, they are for two different things

Comment: @Marek - This link is what you're talking about right? - https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main  I wonder why you can't push this main field into the root level package.json?

Comment: @apricity no i am not talking about that i am talking about https://github.com/NativeScript/template-hello-world from this template is package.json inside app folder problem is that you can have two main files  which depends on using of ng2 or non-ng2 version either app.js or main.(ts/js)  and mostly that would be problem but if you want you can create main entry inside package.json at root project folder and assign path manually which would be troublesome when you can have only one version of package.json at npmjs.com or you can even create your own template with different bootstrap file ;)